# Запись в базу начинается снизу вверх

Tags: phpmyadmin

Подскажите, как сделать чтобы запись была сверху вниз а не снизу вверх?
что добавить в запрос.

Мой:

```
INSERT INTO `Logs` (`T`, `N`, `C`, `V`, `D`) VALUES ('%s','%s', '%s', '%i', '%i.%i.%i | %i:%i')
```

Comment: А что вы имеете ввиду под "верх" и "низ". Если что, в БД нет никакого верха и низа и порядок строк в таблице вообще не определен. Порядок можно задать только при выводе указанием order by

Comment: Насколько я знаю есть возможность прямо в phpMyAdmin сортировать таблицу